# Downloading large file with spring webClient

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I decided to use spring webClient in order to get large files.
Here is my method

```
suspend fun downloadDocument(
    documentId: UUID
): InputStream =
    webClient.get()
        .uri("<some uri>")
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux<DataBuffer>()
        .awaitLast()
        .asInputStream(true)
```

Unfortunately, it does't work as I expected. I receive only small part of data and that's it.

Where is an issue?

Comment: `awaitLast`, as its name indicates, only takes the last data chunk from the stream, that's why you don't see the rest

Comment: I thought this not only takes, but waits the last chunk and hence consumes all data from the stream. 
But if you are right what is the correct way to get all data?

Comment: What is the destination of this data? Do you return it through HTTP to the client? Do you save it somewhere?

Comment: I’m going to save it to some custom storage

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this will work:

```
   suspend fun downloadFile(
        dir: String
    ) {
        val finalCookie = getCookie()
        try {

            val dirPath = Paths.get(dir)
            if (!Files.exists(dirPath)) {
                Files.createDirectories(dirPath)
            }
            val response = webClient.
            get()
                .uri { uriBuilder: UriBuilder ->
                    UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uriBuilder.build())
                        .path("/download/file")
                        .encode()
                        .build(false)
                        .toUri()
                }
                .header(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, finalCookie)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java)

            // How to extract the file name from the response?
            var filename = "./output"
            val destination = Paths.get(dir, filename)
            // Need to use Databuffer so that no memory is used
            DataBufferUtils.write(response, destination).block()
            println("Downloaded $destination")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error in downloading file: $e")
        }
    }
```